# deleting a tbb thread in C++

Tags: c++, tbb

```
tbb::tbb_thread*                    m_tbbTimerThread;
m_tbbTimerThread = new tbb::tbb_thread(&sFirstTimerBlocked, this);
```

// Above thread is spawned.

Later I want to deleted thread in different function. I am doing it as below.

```
if(m_tbbTimerThread != NULL ) 
{
    delete m_tbbTimerThread;
}

m_tbbTimerThread = NULL;
```

Is this right way of doing.

Thanks!

Comment: By later, you mean, in a different function?

Comment: Yes. I edited question to reflect this. Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you think it's not the right way? (You need to be aware that the thread, if it's still running, will continue to run even if you delete the object... is that what you are concerned about?)

Comment: @ as I am not seeing any specific delete function for thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your notion of 'right'.

In general it's a bad idea to destroy a thread object that is still attached to a running thread. C++11's `std::thread` will reward you with a call to `std::terminate` for attempting this. TBB is a lot more forgiving (the thread is simply [detached upon destruction](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/tbb_sa/help/reference/threads/thread_cls/thread_cls_members.htm)), but that does not make the underlying problem go away.

In particular, you might lose your last chance of guaranteeing a clean shutdown. If your process exits, how can you guarantee that the detached thread is not in the middle of writing something to the disk? How can you guarantee that it does not hold on to some persistent handles that will leak if the thread dies without explicitly cleaning them up? Mind you, RAII will probably not kick in if the thread is killed because of the parent process dying. In general, detaching a thread is very problematic for all but the most trivial threads.

So arguably a 'righter' way to shutdown would be:

```
if(m_tbbTimerThread != NULL ) 
{
    if(m_tbbTimerThread->joinable()) {
        <notify the thread to shutdown>
        m_tbbTimerThread->join();
    }
    delete m_tbbTimerThread;
}
```

For non-blocking threads, a single atomic flag might already be enough to implement the shutdown notification.

As with every rule, there is an exception: Sometimes you can shift the monitoring responsibilities to another object, in which case it might be fine to detach the thread. For example, a C++11 [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) call spawns a new thread and returns a future that will become ready once the thread has finished. Waiting on the future serves the same purpose as joining the thread, so there is no need for `async` to return an explicit thread object.